# How to remove the space from top of the list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-layout

I have a swiftui app.

I want to remove the space that is automatically created on the top of the list, but without using the .listStyle(PlainListStyle()).

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("HELLO")
        List{
            ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) {order in
                
                Text("hello")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a picture about of the preview of the above code
[Please see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27rOW.png)

I tried multiple solutions online, like offset: -30, this won't work for me.
Neither the .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
PlainListStyle will make my list elements use the entire screen, and I do not want that.

Comment: Use **ForEach** loop with **ScrollView** instead of the **List**